# UIButton titleLabel make as a circle

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, uilabel

Hello I want to make `UIButton` title label as a circle. So I did in this way.

```
btnAttachments.setTitle(strcount, for: .normal)
btnAttachments.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
btnAttachments.titleLabel?.backgroundColor=com.getRedcolor()
btnAttachments.titleLabel?.font=UIFont.init(name: "Bariol", size: 15)
btnAttachments.titleLabel?.layer.cornerRadius=(btnAttachments.titleLabel?.frame.width)!/2
```

But it doesn't make it as a circle. It looks like this code doen't affect on the `titleLabel`

**UPDATE**

This is what I want to make
[image]

Please help me
Thanks

Comment: I think you forgot btnAttachments.titleLabel.clipsToBounds = YES

Comment: I did and still same :( why is that?

Comment: I think btnAttachments.titleLabel?.frame.width = 0. I try btnAttachments.titleLabel?.layer.cornerRadius = 10. It's working

Comment: you want a circular UIButton?

Comment: try the answer below , you need to set `masksToBounds` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

well first you have to verify that the uibutton has its clipsToBounds true, but incase that s already set and the problem still there, then you probably trying to achieve this in the viewDidLoad which "should" work, but for some reason in some of the xcode 8 versions in the viewDidLoad the layout are still aint final (objects doesnt have their true dimensions set yet) you can verify this by logging the uibutton frame right before you assign the corner radius if you find some incoherent that this is probably the issue , incase this is the issue then you just need to move your code to viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to set MasToBounds

```
btnAttachments.titleLabel?.layer.masksToBounds = true;
```

add this you code will work fine ,

You should set corner redius in `viewDidLayoutSubViews`  or `drawRect`(usually in `UIView` class)

i hope this will help u

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get desired result:

```
let btnAttachments = UIButton(type: .custom)
btnAttachments.setTitle(strcount, for: .normal).setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
btnAttachments.frame = CGRect(x: 160, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50)
btnAttachments.titleLabel?.backgroundColor=com.getRedcolor()
btnAttachments.titleLabel?.font=UIFont.init(name: "Bariol", size: 15)
btnAttachments.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
btnAttachments.clipsToBounds = true
```